# Debugin ionic with wifi and chrome

Tags: android, google-chrome, debugging, ionic-framework

I am trying to debug my oneplus one with wifi and chrome but can get connected to device,
My one plus in on debug mode and adb over network with ip and port.
On my chrome I opened chrome://inspect/#devices insert the ip and port like port and ip+port but nothing is happening....

Thanks for help!

Answer (score -1):

I found the simples solution , just debugging without wifi connect with usb and you are done.